# How can regalia control ayakashi?

Tags: noragami

In Noragami Aragoto episode 02, Bishama's doctor, Kugaha, controls ayakashi. He made it so that the green ayakashi smashes the ground backing him up from Yato's continues attack. Basically, he has ayakashi pets.

There are wolves with masks.

[image: Wolves]

One of them is a green insect-like ayakashi with a mask in the middle of its head.

[image: Insect]

---

They appear to be friendly with Kugaha even though ayakashi are kegare (bad) which has to be killed by Gods and Divine Instruments.

**How is this possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was explained in later episodes.

> The mask was put on the ayakashi's face so that it can be controlled. There was an occasion where the mask was broken and the controller lost control of the ayakashi.